# How to extend Selenium2Library by creating new RobotFramework keywords using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, python-2.7, maven, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to extend the Selenium2Library python library (1.8.0) by implementing new Robot Framework keywords using Selenium WebDriver in Java.

In order to do that, I need to be able to retrieve the WebDriver instance used by the Selenium2Library python library in my Java keyword.

*Please note that I DON'T want to use the Java port of the Selenium 2 (WebDriver) Python library created by Markus Benhardt since it's based on an older version of Selenium2Library so it's clearly outdated.*

I've heard that with Jython 2.7, we can now use the Python version of Selenium2Library on Java... but my question is... how??

My setup is using :

- [Robot Framework Maven Plugin 1.4.7](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/index.html)
- Robot Framework 3.0.2 (as a maven plugin dependency)
- Selenium Server 2.53.1 (as a maven plugin dependency)
- Selenium2Library python library (1.8.0)
- [Robot Framework Javalib Core 1.2.1](https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore)

Here's an extract of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraPathDirectories>
            <extraPathDirectory>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages</extraPathDirectory> 
        </extraPathDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Robot Framework - High level test automation framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone have ever done something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You descibe a desire for a Java solution, but it sounds to me that you'd prefer to stay within the Python context. In Robot Framework the application `robot` (Python) calls `Selenium2Library` (Python) which in turn calls `selenium` (Python) language binding module and that results in a message to the browser `WebDriver`.

As you can tell there is no Java required in a typical Robot Framework setup. If you want to extend the `selenium` Python Module, then have a look at the [robotframework-extendedselenium2library](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library) which is a good example of how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the similar situation, where I had to use Java with Robotframework. The linking of keywords is possible by using the Robot Selenium2library for Java.

You can also create your custom keywords and then link them to the Java Classes for their respective implementation.

Try looking at the project below

https://github.com/mskumar1809/StraitTimesAppiumRobot

which provides java implementation for Robot custom keywords without relying on the Robot outdated Java library